# Fetch a specific item out of a array

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch and echo a specific item out of an array loop, current code is as follows.

```
<?php if(sizeof($post->car_booking_extra) == 0): ?>
N/A
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo implode(array_column($post->car_booking_extra, 'name'), '<br />'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Those echos out the booking extras such as

```
Baby Seat
Charging
Etc.
```

What I'm trying to do is find a specific item in that loop, for example, "Charging" and then display another text.

Something in this direction.

```
<?php if(array_column($post->car_booking_extra, 'name') == "Charging" ); ?>
DISPLAY THIS
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm not very familiar with best practice on this, all i tried such as the above example gives me errors, anyone have an idea what i could try?.

Tried as in the second example above, all i get are errors.

Comment: _"What I'm trying to do is find a specific item in that loop"_ - what "loop"? You do not have any explicit loop, you are just imploding the array values into a single string value. So, either manipulate the content of your array itself before that; or switch to using an actual loop to generate your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `in_array()`

```
<?php if(in_array('Charging',array_column($post->car_booking_extra, 'name'))); ?>
DISPLAY THIS
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note: Make sure that column has values in uppercase as you want to check uppercase value

https://3v4l.org/lLkqk